# Changing a MVVM DataTemplate's cell on population of data

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

EDIT: It seems the problem is because the DataTemplate won't run again, even if it's called. How do I force the DataTemplate to run when I call it a 2nd time?

I have a listview where each line is a checkbox and a label. If a user selects the label or checkbox, the checkbox is activated and the item is added to a selectedList. There are other ways to add/remove items from this list, outside of this listview.

When the listview is activated and shows, I want the current items on the selectedList to show as checked. I can do this by running a comparison between the selectedList and all the items, if it exists on both, I check it.

Here's the problem. The labels text is a bindable property, so it is not available during the data templates initialization (so I can't check if it's value is on the selectedItem's list). The code below works on the first time the listview shows (I also tried ChildAdded, didn't work).

```
cell.Appearing += (s, e) =>
                {
                    foreach (FloorDetailsViewModel floor in _viewModel.SelectedFloorsList)
                    {
                        if (floor.Name == label.Text)
                            checkBox.Source = activeImage;
                    }
                };
```

[image]

Is there a way to always run that comparison code whenever the

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manually rerun the DataTemplate just by calling it. You have to set the DataTemplate's ItemSource to null and then set it back to the new value. This should cause the entire DataTemplate to refresh. I don't know why you have to do it this way..but that's how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong. You should have a Bindable CheckBox so you don't have to do nothing outside MVVM (The checkbox will be automatically checked or unchecked depending on some values in the Model)

Comment: How would the Bindable CheckBox work on the VM side? There would have to be a checkbox for every floor item, which is variable. The only way that would work is to add a "selected" property to my Floor class, which is a crappy solution. I don't want to include a property to a class just for the sake of getting a listview to show properly. 

To clarify, the listview's ItemSource is a list of Floor objects. The label is set to the Floor's name, the name of course deserves to be a part of the class. A "selected" property for one listview does not.

Comment: If your checkbox is in the ViewCell (like "name"), it should be in the Floor object. This is my opinion

Comment: That would work but I don't think it is a good solution. I was able to do it by setting the DataTemplates ItemSource to null then back to the correct value. This made it so the cell's OnAppear listener was being called correctly. Also not a good solution, but it seems there may not be a good one.